# Launching .app bundle fails with LSOpenURLsWithRole() error -10810, but works in debugger

Tags: applications

I made a macos app bundle with cmake.
I try to open the bundle with `open bundle.app`, which gives me

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file bundle.app.
```

However, I can both run

```
$ lldb bundle.app
$ run
```

and `bundle.app/Contents/MacOS/executable` with no problem.

What does this error try to tell me? Apple's developer documentation doesn't seem to map error codes to human-readable descriptions.

**Update**

I am building the app on a Mojave computer. Strangely, it launches fine on a different Big Sur machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloaded apps do not start, error -10658](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/downloaded-apps-do-not-start-error-10658)

Comment: No, both the app and the executable are marked as executable. I am not seeing any permission problems, although I'm not sure what those would be other than the execute bit.

Comment: What happens if you double-click `bundle.app`? Can you add the output of `ls -l bundle.app/Contents/MacOS/executable`?

Comment: Nothing happens. I am looking at the console log and it seems to spawn entries such as `MacOS error: -67062` and `UNIX error exception: 8`, but there's nothing obvious to me. The permissions on the executable are currently `-rwxrwxrwx`, as I tried simply allowing everything for a test.